# convert typescript react calculator button component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

- I'm trying to figure out what I'm missing in TypeScript to convert this calculator app into TypeScript.
- I created a type ButtonProps, but I'm not sure what to set the handleClick or children to, other than 'any'.
- Also, the function 'isOperator', I set to take in a number or string because it checks if it's not a number or if it's a specific string. However, typescript is yelling at me: This expression is not callable. No constituent of type 'string | number' is callable.
- Can you help me figure out the types I need to make this work?
- Is there a site that you recommend that can help figure types out? Seems quite confusing.

  ```
    import React, {FC} from 'react';
    import '../styling/button.css';

    // create types for props
    type ButtonProps = {
      handleClick: any;
      children: any;
    }

    const isOperator:number | string = val => {
      return !isNaN(val) || val === "." || val === "=";
    }

    // generic type, FC
    export const Button: FC <ButtonProps> = ({children, handleClick}) => {
      return (
        <div className={`button-wrapper ${isOperator(children) ? null : "operator"}`}
            onClick={() => handleClick(children)}
        >
          {children}
        </div>
      )
    }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things to point out about the code you've pointed:

```
const isOperator: number | string = (val) => {
  return !isNaN(val) || val === "." || val === "=";
};
```

- You've typed `isOperator` as being either a `number` or a `string`,
  but you've then assigned a function to it. This is why you are getting "This expression is not callable" - because you've told TypeScript that the variable is a `number` or a `string` - neither of which are callable. I suspect what you *meant* to assign those types to the `val` parameter
- `isNaN(...)` only takes a `number` parameter, so when you make the above correction, you'll see that you get a further type error here. This is a reasonable error, since the job if `isNaN` is to check whether a `number` is set to the special value `NaN`, so you'll need to correct the logic to narrow the type first

To fix these problems, you can do something like this:

```
const isOperator = (val: number | string) => {
  return (typeof val === "number" && !isNaN(val)) || val === "." || val === "=";
};
```

next to your props:

```
type ButtonProps = {
  handleClick: any;
  children: any;
};
```

- You don't need to specify the `children` prop: because you are using `FC<ButtonProps>` the `children` prop is already there.
- HandleClick needs to a be a function type with a parameter that takes a `ReactNode` (since that's the type of `props.children` in this case, and you want to pass it into that function

So that leaves you with this:

```
type ButtonProps = {
  handleClick: (children: React.ReactNode) => void;
};
```

So you are getting there now, but typescript won't accept this, because actually `props.children` is of type `React.ReactNode` (not just `string | number`) and so when you try to pass it into isOperator, you will get a type error.

Thankfully, `React.ReactNode` is compatible with `number | string` (as it is [just a union type which contains those options](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/35f7441d374bfa7be8e3e9576fd1388333df49cb/packages/shared/ReactTypes.js#L10-L24), so you can just change `isOperator` to the following:

```
const isOperator = (val: React.ReactNode) => {
  return (typeof val === "number" && !isNaN(val)) || val === "." || val === "=";
};
```

Once you make this last change, your code should compile.

Comment: wow that was thorough, thank you. just a couple quick questions to clarify. when you did, typeof val === "number" && !isNaN(val)), how does it know what the string "number" means?

Comment: handleClick: (children: React.ReactNode) => void; you set the arg children to React.ReactNode because that's what you do for reusable components? like, because if user clicks a button, aka reusable component, that would be the arg passed into handleClick function? I'm just rephrasing to clarify for myself, but does that sound correct?

Comment: The `typeof` operator is a special operator that returns a string depending on the type of its argument (see the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)). For `typeof val`, It will *only* return the string "number" if `val` is indeed a number. TypeScript knows this so it will do a thing called [type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html), in that it knows that execution is only going to pass on to the right hand side of the `&&` if that is true, therefore when this happens, `val` can only be `number`.

Comment: The reason I set the arg to `React.ReactNode` was because when you called that function, you passed in the `children` prop, and that's the type of the `children` prop.